# Select from XML with namespace in T-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery

I am trying to get data out of XML but I can't get it to work. The cross apply yields no rows.

The XML looks like this:

```
<Declaration xmlns="urn:se:customs:datamodel:WCO:Declaration:1" xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:md="urn:se:customs:datamodel:WCO:DocumentMetaData:1" xmlns:eia="http://tullverket.se/ei/addressing-1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <FunctionalReferenceID>NE07855393</FunctionalReferenceID>
  <TypeCode>IMA</TypeCode>
  <Agent>
    <ID>SE5567115695</ID>
    <FunctionCode>2</FunctionCode>
  </Agent>
  <Declarant>
    <Name>CHRISTER EKMAN</Name>
    <ID>SE0000000000</ID>
    <RoleCode>DT</RoleCode>
    <Address>
      <CityName>TÄBY</CityName>
      <CountryCode>SE</CountryCode>
      <Line>LÅNGA RADEN 2</Line>
      <PostcodeID>18352</PostcodeID>
    </Address>
  </Declarant>
  <Declarant>
    <ID>SE5567115695</ID>
    <RoleCode>ZP</RoleCode>
  </Declarant>
  <Declarant>
    <ID>SE5567115695</ID>
    <RoleCode>ZG</RoleCode>
  </Declarant>
  <GoodsShipment>
    <TransactionNatureCode>1</TransactionNatureCode>
    <InvoiceCurrencyCode>USD</InvoiceCurrencyCode>
    <AdditionalDocument>
      <ID>DEKL</ID>
      <TypeCode>N325</TypeCode>
    </AdditionalDocument>
    <AdditionalInformation>
      <StatementCode>PRIVA</StatementCode>
    </AdditionalInformation>
    <Consignment>
      <ContainerCode>0</ContainerCode>
      <ArrivalTransportMeans>
        <ModeCode>5</ModeCode>
      </ArrivalTransportMeans>
      <BorderTransportMeans>
        <RegistrationNationalityCode>SE</RegistrationNationalityCode>
        <ModeCode>5</ModeCode>
      </BorderTransportMeans>
      <GoodsLocation>
        <Name>BJL</Name>
        <TypeCode>B</TypeCode>
        <Address>
          <TypeCode>Y</TypeCode>
        </Address>
      </GoodsLocation>
      <TransportContractDocument>
        <ID>UV110706135DE</ID>
        <TypeCode>N750</TypeCode>
      </TransportContractDocument>
    </Consignment>
    <Destination>
      <CountryCode>SE</CountryCode>
    </Destination>
    <ExportCountry>
      <ID>US</ID>
    </ExportCountry>
    <Exporter>
      <Name>THEPHOTOSTICK</Name>
      <Address>
        <CityName>HAXTUN</CityName>
        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
        <Line>X</Line>
        <PostcodeID>80731</PostcodeID>
      </Address>
    </Exporter>
    <GovernmentAgencyGoodsItem>
      <SequenceNumeric>1</SequenceNumeric>
      <StatisticalValueAmount>3151.62</StatisticalValueAmount>
      <Commodity>
        <Description>USB MEMORY WITH SOFTWARE</Description>
        <Classification>
          <ID>854232</ID>
          <IdentificationTypeCode>HSU</IdentificationTypeCode>
        </Classification>
        <Classification>
          <ID>19</ID>
          <IdentificationTypeCode>KNR</IdentificationTypeCode>
        </Classification>
        <Classification>
          <ID>00</ID>
          <IdentificationTypeCode>TAR</IdentificationTypeCode>
        </Classification>
        <DutyTaxFee>
          <AdValoremTaxBaseAmount>3151</AdValoremTaxBaseAmount>
          <DutyRegimeCode>100</DutyRegimeCode>
          <TaxRateNumeric>25</TaxRateNumeric>
          <TypeCode>B00</TypeCode>
          <Payment>
            <MethodCode>E</MethodCode>
          </Payment>
        </DutyTaxFee>
        <GoodsMeasure>
          <GrossMassMeasure>0.20</GrossMassMeasure>
          <NetNetWeightMeasure>0.20</NetNetWeightMeasure>
        </GoodsMeasure>
        <InvoiceLine>
          <ItemChargeAmount>300</ItemChargeAmount>
        </InvoiceLine>
      </Commodity>
      <CustomsValuation>
        <MethodCode>1</MethodCode>
      </CustomsValuation>
      <GovernmentProcedure>
        <CurrentCode>40</CurrentCode>
        <PreviousCode>00</PreviousCode>
      </GovernmentProcedure>
      <Origin>
        <CountryCode>CN</CountryCode>
        <TypeCode>1</TypeCode>
      </Origin>
      <Packaging>
        <MarksNumbersID>UV110706135DE</MarksNumbersID>
        <QuantityQuantity>1</QuantityQuantity>
        <TypeCode>PC</TypeCode>
      </Packaging>
      <UCR>
        <TraderAssignedReferenceID>UV110706135DE</TraderAssignedReferenceID>
      </UCR>
      <AdditionalReference>
        <TypeCode>Y069</TypeCode>
      </AdditionalReference>
    </GovernmentAgencyGoodsItem>
    <Invoice>
      <AmountAmount>300</AmountAmount>
    </Invoice>
    <PreviousDocument>
      <ID>UV110706135DE</ID>
      <TypeCode>N750</TypeCode>
    </PreviousDocument>
    <TradeTerms>
      <ConditionCode>EXW</ConditionCode>
      <LocationName>TÄBY</LocationName>
      <CountryCode>SE</CountryCode>
    </TradeTerms>
    <UCR>
      <TraderAssignedReferenceID>UV110706135DE</TraderAssignedReferenceID>
    </UCR>
  </GoodsShipment>
  <Importer>
    <Name>CHRISTER EKMAN</Name>
    <ID>SE0000000000</ID>
    <Address>
      <CityName>TÄBY</CityName>
      <CountryCode>SE</CountryCode>
      <Line>LÅNGA RADEN 2</Line>
      <PostcodeID>18352</PostcodeID>
    </Address>
  </Importer>
</Declaration>
```

How do I query from it?

If I declare a variable without the `Declaration` tag, I can make it work.

I want to get the value X from the path:

```
GoodsShipment/Exporter/Address/Line/
```

Comment: What is your attempt? You forgot to include it. You say your "`CROSS APPLY`"  returned no results; do you mean you're attempt to use the `nodes` and `value` method?Did you define your namespace(s) in your attempt(s)?

Comment: You need to use the default namespace : `xmlns="urn:se:customs:datamodel:WCO:Declaration:1"`

Comment: Like this?;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:se:customs:datamodel:WCO:Declaration:1')
SELECT t.r.query('.') as fullvalue
FROM (
 SELECT cast([XML_CONTENT] as xml) AS [XML] 
 FROM [PRESTAGE_TIMP].[dbo].[TIMP_DOL_XML]
) R1
 CROSS APPLY R1.[XML].nodes('GoodsShipment') AS t(r)

Comment: I am trying to select the value X from the xml path GoodsShipment/Exporter/Address/Line. Something like this ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:se:customs:datamodel:WCO:Declaration:1')
SELECT r.value('.','varchar(50)') AS Line
FROM (
 SELECT cast([XML_CONTENT] as xml) AS [XML] 
 FROM [PRESTAGE_TIMP].[dbo].[TIMP_DOL_XML]
) R1
 CROSS APPLY R1.[XML].nodes('GoodsShipment/Exporter/Address/Line') AS t(r)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work with the help of the comments.
This is how it is supposed to look with a default namespace tag:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:se:customs:datamodel:WCO:Declaration:1')
SELECT DISTINCT r.value('.','varchar(max)') AS Line
FROM (
    SELECT cast([XML_CONTENT] as xml) AS [XML] 
    FROM [PRESTAGE_TIMP].[dbo].[TIMP_DOL_XML]
) R1
 CROSS APPLY R1.[XML].nodes('/Declaration/GoodsShipment/Exporter/Address/Line') AS t(r)
```